# FontFace no funciona

Tags: html, css, html5, scss

El texto no me reconoce la fontfamily importada en el font-face sabrian decirme el porque

```
 @font-face{
  font-family: 'pruebas';
  src: url("http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2934/=VeraSeBd.ttf");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}
.description{
  color: $text-color-black;
  font-size: $size-9;
  font-family: 'pruebas';
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 5):

En el CSS estás aplicando esa fuente solamente a los elementos que tengan la clase `description`:

```
.description{
  color: $text-color-black;
  font-size: $size-9;
  font-family: 'pruebas';
}
```

Por tanto, para que funcione tienes que ponerle esa clase a los elementos. Veamos varios elementos unos con esa clase y otros sin ella, la fuente en efecto funciona:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'pruebas';
  src: url("http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2934/=VeraSeBd.ttf");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

.description {
  color: $text-color-black;
  font-size: $size-9;
  font-family: 'pruebas';
}
```

```html
<p class="description">This is Bitstream Vera Serif Bold.</p>
<p class="description">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Texto normal</p>
```

Si quieres que se aplique a todo el documento, puedes hacerlo así:

```css
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold";
    src: url("http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2934/=VeraSeBd.ttf");
  }

    body { font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold", serif }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```